# JavaScript: Opacity should reduce to 0 and then become negative

Tags: javascript, opacity

I have a javaScript function.

JavaScript:

```
function opacZero(object){
    var presentOpacity = (object.style.opacity);
    object.style.opacity =presentOpacity-0.2;
    setTimeout( function(){opacZero(object)}, 40);
}
```

Now when I pass som eobject to this function, its opacity should reduce till 0 and go beyond 0 (as I am not clearing the timeout anywhere). But this is not happening. The opacity reduces to 0.20000000000000007 and reduces no more. But when I subtract 0.3 (or more) instead of 0.2, it is giving the desired result. But why not with numbers less than 0.2. I have no idea why this is happening. Help PLease

Comment: I don't think the browser will like you for wanting negative opacity. How should that be implemented?

Comment: Thats okay! but logically it should go beyong 0  which is happening perfectly when I subtract 0.3 or more. But not when I am subtracting 0.2 or less. Why is it so?

Comment: Why it should go beyond 0 ? its setTimeout not setInterval function

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bhTNC/

Comment: @Juhana I want the test to completely disappear. How to do that?

Comment: When opacity is < 0.3, then set style `visibility: hidden` or `display; none`.  You're probably dealing with floating point inaccuracies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to how Javascript handles floating point numbers. Check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/elegant-workaround-for-javascript-floating-point-number-problem) for some suggestions on how to work around it.

**EDIT**

Here's a way to work around it:

```
function opacZero(object){
    var presentOpacity = Math.floor(object.style.opacity * 10);
    object.style.opacity = (presentOpacity - 2) / 10;
    setTimeout( function(){opacZero(object)}, 40);
}
```

Comment: Solved the Problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems a little more straightforward to just check for the troublesome small values and force those to `0`.  Also probably a good idea to stop the timer once you hit `0`:

```
function opacZero(object){
    var newOpacity = object.style.opacity - 0.2;
    if (newOpacity < 0.2) {
        newOpacity = 0;
    }
    object.style.opacity = newOpacity;
    if (newOpacity !== 0) {
        setTimeout(function(){opacZero(object)}, 40);
    }
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8qkFN/

Or, if you want something briefer:

```
function opacZero(object){
    object.style.opacity = object.style.opacity < 0.4 ? 0 : object.style.opacity - 0.2;
    if (object.style.opacity != 0) {
        setTimeout(function(){opacZero(object)}, 40);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible work around:

```
function opacZero(object){
    curOpac = curOpac < 0.1 ? 0 : curOpac - 0.2;
    object.style.opacity = curOpac;
    setTimeout( function(){
        opacZero(object)
    }, 400);
    console.log( curOpac );
}

var test = document.getElementById( 'test' ),
    curOpac = 1;
test.style.opacity = 1;
opacZero( test );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/bhTNC/1/